# C++ unable to dock AppBar

Tags: c++, winapi, codeblocks, dock, appbar

I am trying to dock the AppBar on the right side of the desktop screen. Therefore I have included only code for the right. I am not looking to move the AppBar or have the auto-hide feature enabled. Given below is the code:

```
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <commctrl.h>
    #include "resource.h"
    #include <stdio.h>

    #define Tool_Width 300

    HINSTANCE hInst;
    RECT desktop;
    BOOL fBarRegistered;
    UINT uCallBack;

    void RegisterBar(HWND);
    void ABSetPos(HWND);

    BOOL CALLBACK DlgMain(HWND hwndDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
        switch(uMsg){
            case WM_INITDIALOG:{
                SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETWORKAREA,0, &desktop, 0);
                RegisterBar(hwndDlg);
            }
            return TRUE;

            case WM_CLOSE:{
                RegisterBar(hwndDlg);
                EndDialog(hwndDlg, 0);
            }
            return TRUE;

        }
        return FALSE;
    }

    int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd){
        hInst=hInstance;
        InitCommonControls();
        return DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(DLG_MAIN), NULL, (DLGPROC)DlgMain);
    }

    void RegisterBar(HWND hwndDlg){
        APPBARDATA abd;
        abd.cbSize = (DWORD) sizeof(APPBARDATA);
        abd.hWnd = hwndDlg;
        if (!fBarRegistered){
            uCallBack = RegisterWindowMessage("AppBarMessage");
            abd.uCallbackMessage = uCallBack;

            SHAppBarMessage((DWORD)ABM_NEW, &abd);
            fBarRegistered = true;

            ABSetPos(hwndDlg);
        }
        else{
            SHAppBarMessage((DWORD)ABM_REMOVE, &abd);
            fBarRegistered = false;
        }
    }

    void ABSetPos(HWND hwndDlg){
        APPBARDATA abd;
        abd.cbSize = (DWORD) sizeof(APPBARDATA);
        abd.hWnd = hwndDlg;
        abd.uEdge = (UINT)ABE_RIGHT;

        abd.rc.top = 0;
        abd.rc.bottom = desktop.bottom;
        abd.rc.right = desktop.right;
        abd.rc.left = abd.rc.right - Tool_Width;

        SHAppBarMessage((DWORD)ABM_QUERYPOS, &abd);
        abd.rc.left= abd.rc.right - Tool_Width;
        SHAppBarMessage((DWORD)ABM_SETPOS, &abd);

        MoveWindow(hwndDlg, abd.rc.left, abd.rc.top, abd.rc.right - abd.rc.left, abd.rc.bottom - abd.rc.top, false);
    }
```

When I run this code, space is allotted on the right side but the MoveWindow does not dock the window into that space. If I comment ABM_SETPOS, MoveWindow moves and sizes dialog on the right but does not dock.

I referenced code from this website [C# sample code](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6741/AppBar-using-C)

Comment: You never check return values of functions, `abd` is used uninitialized.

Comment: @VTT The return value is 1 for all SHAppBarMessage functions. Should we initialize 'structs' in C++. I am using CodeBlocks 17.12. I had tried using 'new' to initialize 'abd'. error: conversion from 'APPBARDATA* {aka _AppBarData*}' to non-scalar type 'APPBARDATA {aka _AppBarData}' requested